# JPA 2 Remote Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, detachedcriteria

Is there any way that criteria for queries can be built on a remote (Swing/SWT etc) client?  We've been using the DetachedCriteria functionality in Hibernate for quite some time, but would like to use standard JPA 2.

If not, could the code from hibernate be re-factored to create the remote API?  Or is this something that might come along in JPA 2.1?

Comment: "is this something that might come along in JPA 2.1?" - this is better asked to the persons involved in working on the relevant JSR. I'm afraid, you might not get an answer to that part of the question.

Comment: Even as of today, I still can't bet an answer.  I might have to resort to praying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. Consider leaving a comment on Linda DeMichiel's Blog (the spec Lead) or sending your input to the expert group:

> #### [JPA.next - Thinking about the Future](http://blogs.oracle.com/ldemichiel/entry/jpa_next_thinking_about_the)
>
> ...
>
> Feedback from the community is very
>   important to us, so please share your
>   thoughts on where you think we should
>   go next. What features do you think
>   are most important to add in JPA 2.1?
>
> Feel free to comment here, and please
>   also share your input by posting to
>   the JPA 2.0 feedback list,
>   jsr-317-feedback@sun.com. Input sent
>   to it forwards to all of the members
>   of the JPA 2.0 expert group for
>   consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll post on there :)