# How to count the number of rows of a JPA 2 CriteriaQuery in a generic JPA DAO?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, count, pagination

I'm new in JPA and want to implement a generic JPA DAO and need to find the number of rows of a query result set to implement pagination. After searching the web, I can't find a practical way to do that. Here is the code suggested in many articles:

```
public <T> Long findCountByCriteria(CriteriaQuery<?> criteria) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Long> countCriteria = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<?> entityRoot = countCriteria.from(criteria.getResultType());
    countCriteria.select(builder.count(entityRoot));
    countCriteria.where(criteria.getRestriction());

    return em.createQuery(countCriteria).getSingleResult();
}
```

However, that code doesn't work when using `join`. Is there any way to count the rows of a query result set using the JPA Criteria API?

UPDATE :
here is the code that create CriteriaQuery :

```
    CriteriaQuery<T> queryDefinition = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(this.entityClass);
    Root<T> root = queryDefinition.from(this.entityClass);
```

and some joins may be added to the root until the query have been executed:

```
public Predicate addPredicate(Root<T> root) {
                Predicate predicate = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().ge(root.join(Entity_.someList).get("id"), 13);
                return predicate;
}
```

and the generated exception is like :

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path:
>   'generatedAlias1.id' [select count(generatedAlias0) from entity.Entity
>   as generatedAlias0 where ( generatedAlias0.id>=13L ) and (
>   (generatedAlias1.id<=34L ) )]

which generatedAlias1 should be on Entity and generatedAlias0 should be on the association that I joined on that.
Note that I implement Join properly because when I execute query without count query it executes without error and the Join works properly but when I try to execute count query it throws exception.

Comment: Can you show us how have you defined CriteriaQuery<?> criteria

Comment: Check out some other answers to similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001289/jpa-hibernate-criteriabuilder-how-to-create-query-using-relationship-object/9002225#9002225 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025196/how-to-use-jpa-criteria-api-when-joining-many-tables/9025656#9025656

Comment: @perissf tnx 4 ur attention. I check out those, but didn't help me. i don't know how to get row counts when using join in my JPA criteria Query.

Comment: Still you have not shown all your code. How are you generating the predicates for the WHERE statement? The joins should produce predicates for the WHERE. What error are you getting?

Comment: @perissf I add more details to main post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7137/discussion-between-perissf-and-new-to-java)

Comment: @perissf: I've got similar problem, the key issue here is that you can get Predicates from one CriteriaQuery (using Predicate oldPredicate = criteria.getRestriction()) but you cannot set them in another query since they are bound to first CriteriaQuery by Root object. Or rather you can call newCriteriaQuery.where(oldPredicate); but when you try to execute it you receive QuerySyntaxException as described in post

Comment: @regis: please ask a new question with all the necessary details. Anyway I think that's never a good idea to re-use Predicates written for another query as you are describing

Comment: @perissf: The feature I was looking for is an equivalent of Hibernate's Detached Criteria. Unfortunatelly it looks like there is no such option in JPA 2.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636457/jpa-2-remote-criteria

Answer (score 9):

I've done this:

```
public Long getRowCount(CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery,CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,Root<?> root){
    CriteriaQuery<Long> countCriteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<?> entityRoot = countCriteria.from(root.getJavaType());
    entityRoot.alias(root.getAlias());
    doJoins(root.getJoins(),entityRoot);
    countCriteria.select(criteriaBuilder.count(entityRoot));
    countCriteria.where(criteriaQuery.getRestriction());
    return this.entityManager.createQuery(countCriteria).getSingleResult();
}

private void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins,Root<?> root_){
    for(Join<?,?> join: joins){
        Join<?,?> joined = root_.join(join.getAttribute().getName(),join.getJoinType());
        doJoins(join.getJoins(), joined);
    }
}

private void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins,Join<?,?> root_){
    for(Join<?,?> join: joins){
        Join<?,?> joined = root_.join(join.getAttribute().getName(),join.getJoinType());
        doJoins(join.getJoins(),joined);
    }
}
```

of course you do not need Root as input parameter you could get it from criteria query,

Answer (score 4):

@lubo08 gave correct answer - **kudos for him**.
But for two corner cases his/her code won't work:

- When criteria query's restrictions use aliases for joins - then `COUNT` also require these aliases to be set.
- When criteria query use **fetch join** [`root.fetch(..)` instead of `root.join(..)`]

So for completeness I dared to improve his/her solution and present below:

```
public <T> long count(final CriteriaBuilder cb, final CriteriaQuery<T> criteria,
        Root<T> root) {
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = createCountQuery(cb, criteria, root);
    return this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
}

private <T> CriteriaQuery<Long> createCountQuery(final CriteriaBuilder cb,
        final CriteriaQuery<T> criteria, final Root<T> root) {

    final CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    final Root<T> countRoot = countQuery.from(criteria.getResultType());

    doJoins(root.getJoins(), countRoot);
    doJoinsOnFetches(root.getFetches(), countRoot);

    countQuery.select(cb.count(countRoot));
    countQuery.where(criteria.getRestriction());

    countRoot.alias(root.getAlias());

    return countQuery.distinct(criteria.isDistinct());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void doJoinsOnFetches(Set<? extends Fetch<?, ?>> joins, Root<?> root) {
    doJoins((Set<? extends Join<?, ?>>) joins, root);
}

private void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins, Root<?> root) {
    for (Join<?, ?> join : joins) {
        Join<?, ?> joined = root.join(join.getAttribute().getName(), join.getJoinType());
        joined.alias(join.getAlias());
        doJoins(join.getJoins(), joined);
    }
}

private void doJoins(Set<? extends Join<?, ?>> joins, Join<?, ?> root) {
    for (Join<?, ?> join : joins) {
        Join<?, ?> joined = root.join(join.getAttribute().getName(), join.getJoinType());
        joined.alias(join.getAlias());
        doJoins(join.getJoins(), joined);
    }
}
```

Although it is still **not perfect**, because only one root is honored.
But I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: I had to add a Predicate `cb.equal(countRoot, root)`, otherwise there is a "cartesian join"

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you where your problem is, but I can tell you that count queries with joins work well, at least in `eclipselink` jpa. My guess is that this is standard stuff, so it should work also in hibernate. I would start by simplifying your code in order to catch where the problem is. 
I see that you have copied some pieces of your cont query from your main query. Maybe you can try to change a little bit this approach, just for debugging purpose.

What I do usually is:

```
CriteriaQuery cqCount = builder.createQuery();
Root<T> root = cq.from(T.class);
cqCount.select(builder.count(root)); 
ListJoin<T, Entity> join = root.join(T_.someList);
Predicate predicate = builder.ge(join.get(Entity_.id), "myId"); 
cqCount.where(predicate);
TypedQuery<Long> q = em.createQuery(cqCount);
```

Looking at your pseudo-code, it seems that you are using the wrong class in the join method: it must be the starting class, not the target class.

Comment: Reading your simple answer after a good night just got me out of 10 hours of struggling with this join query and criteria stuff... : )