# JPA CriteriaQuery: getCount + condition

Tags: jpa, count, predicate, criteriaquery

I try to get all the count of Articles (Article.class) which are not analyzed (analyzed == false).
Sadly the following code returns absolutely wrong numbers.
Would anybody know why?

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
query.select(cb.count(query.from(Article.class)));
Root<Article> articles = query.from(Article.class);
Predicate condition = cb.isFalse(articles.get(Article_.analyzed));
query.where(condition);
TypedQuery<Long> unanalyzedArticlesAmount = entityManager.createQuery(query);
return unanalyzedArticlesAmount.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally read this post:
[How to count the number of rows of a JPA 2 CriteriaQuery in a generic JPA DAO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051734/how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-of-a-jpa-2-criteriaquery-in-a-generic-jpa-dao)

and found the following solution:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery();    
Root<Article> root = query.from(Article.class);
query.select(cb.count(root));
Predicate condition = cb.isFalse(root.get(Article_.analyzed));
query.where(condition);
TypedQuery<Long> unanalyzedArticlesAmount = entityManager.createQuery(query);
return unanalyzedArticlesAmount.getSingleResult();
```